Batch Script to Open and Close a Python Script on a schedule
There is an AngelScript plugin that allows players to listen to music and online radio within the game itself, using the in-game microphone system. For this to work, the game must run a Metamod .dll (a program that launches alongside the game's .dll file) and a Python script (radio_client.py).
I have encountered a problem with restarting or using a taskkill command. The complication arises because the Python script is launched within Command Prompt rather than directly within Python. Since I am already using Command Prompt for several other tasks, force-closing the cmd.exe process would disrupt these tasks. My goal is to create a script that closes and reopens radio_client.py on a timer. Ideally, this would occur every 12 hours, as the radio program tends to break after an unspecified duration and requires resetting. Having to manually close and restart the program has become frustrating.
:restart
radio_client.py
echo "restarting radio"
timeout /t 5
goto restart


What is configured in scheduled task for the property Start in which defines the current working directory on Windows Task Scheduler calling the the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess or CreateProcessAsUser passed with lpCurrentDirectory to the called function? Please export the scheduled task to an XML file, [edit] the question and add the XML contents.

radio_client.py is not an executable, it is a Python script file. A script needs a script interpreter for execution. The second line should be at least python.exe radio_client.py and best "C:\Path\To\Python\bin\python.exe" "C:\Path To\Script\radio_client.py". There can be used "%~dp0radio_client.py" if the Python script file is stored in the same directory as the batch file. %~dp0 expands to full path of the batch file directory always ending with the directory separator \.

timeout /t 5 should be modified to %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 1>NUL or %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NOBREAK 1>NUL. The scheduled task property Program/script should be %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe and the property arguments should be /D /C "C:\Path to Batch\FileName.cmd".

Does this look correct?
I don't think the radio_client.py needs changed because its launching from the same folder.
:restart
radio_client.py
echo "restarting radio"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /D /C "C:\Users..............................\Radio\radio_start.cmd /T 5 1>NUL
goto restart

When you run your scheduled task, if you have not specifically input the working directory, the batch file, or even the python script, will need to set it instead. Your scheduler does not automagically know which directory to use, and does not default to your batch file directory location.

This is currently what I am working with
:restart
"C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users...\Desktop\darkfuture backup\darkfuture\servers\1\serverfiles\svencoop\scripts\plugins\Radio\radio_client.py"
echo "restarting radio"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /D /C "C:\Users...\Desktop\darkfuture backup\darkfuture\servers\1\serverfiles\svencoop\scripts\plugins\Radio\radio_start.cmd" /T 5 1>NUL
goto restart
This sucessfully launches it but I see no indication that it is closing or reopening it

timeout doesn't take /D or /C parameters. Is that a copy/paste error or your actual command? The way it's written in your comments it won't work, but give an error message.

I had that because of what Mofi said:  "and the property arguments should be /D /C "C:\Path to Batch\FileName.cmd""

he didn't say, they are for timeout, but he said they are for cmd.exe (where they definitively make sense)
